# Persistent background worker in Android Flutter App that fetch Web API every 30 seconds

Tags: android, flutter, dart, backgroundworker, intervals

I'm developing Android only app on Flutter. My app needs to call some Web APIs in the background every 30 seconds. The background worker should keep running even if the user or Android OS closes my app's main activity.

I know that doing something in the background too frequently will drain the battery very quickly and it is considered bad practice. But still, I need to do it every 30 seconds.

The target platform of my app is Android 7.0 or higher.

Any ideas how can I implement this in Flutter?

Answer (score -1):

Try to add **Timer** I have already use Timer (below code) in my app my problem is solved

> Timer: A count-down timer that can be configured to fire once or
> repeatedly.

Declare Timer inside your class

```
 Timer timer;
 int counter = 0;
```

Create `initState()` method for timer

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timer = Timer.periodic(
      Duration(seconds: 30),
      (Timer t) => addValue(),
    );
  }
```

Create function for addValue it is increased

```
void addValue() {
    setState(() {
      counter++;
    });
    }
```

your page auto reload every 30 seconds

OR you just use setState method inside your API call function like below

```
setState(() {  });
```

Comment: Will your solution work on the background when my app's main window is not active?